# Insertar tabla código PHP

Tags: php, html, html5, html-tabla

En el siguiente código en PHP, ¿Cómo podría introducir una tabla de tal manera que quede como la de la imagen? He probado con las etiquetas table y las que hacen referencia, pero no se situarlas correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla de multiplicar

## Tabla de multiplicar

```
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST["enviar"]) && (!empty($_POST["numero"]))) {
         $numero=$_POST["numero"];
         $incremento=1;
         for ($j=1; $j<=$numero; $j++) {
            for ($i=0; $i<11; $i++) {
                $multiplica=$incremento*$i; 
                echo $incremento. "x" .$i. "=" .$multiplica. "<br>"; 
            }
            $incremento++;
            echo "<br>";
         }
     }else {

       ?>  

    <form name="formulario" action=' <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method="post">
    <div>
    <label for="name">Introduce el número para la tabla de multiplicar: </label>
    <input type="text" name="numero"/> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar">
    <input type="reset" value="Borrar" name="Borrar">
    <br>

    <?php
     }
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero tendras que recoger el valor del numero y separando tu codigo.

EJ:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Tabla Multiplicar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tabla de multiplicar</h1>
        <form action="tabla.php" method="post">
            Introduce un número: 
            <input type="text" name="numero"/><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Multiplicar"/>            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`tabla.php` :

```
<html>
<body>

<?php


$valor = intval($_POST['numero']);

for($i=1;$i < $valor ; $i++){ // loop del numero de tablas para imprimir

    ?>
    <h1> Tabla del <?php echo $i ?></h1>

    <ul>
        <?php
        for($s=1;$s <= 10 ; $s++){ // loop para el numero de incremento
          if ($s%2==0){ // Es par $s
          echo "<li><span style='color:red'>$i x $s = ";
              echo $i*$s;
              echo "</span></li>";
          }
          else{ // Es impar $s
          echo "<li>$i x $s = ";
              echo $i*$s;
              echo "</li>";
          }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>

<?php
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Por último solo debes asociar dichas tablas en un contenedor `div` y crear el css para que quede como tu indicas.

edit: si lo que quieres es hacerlo en la misma página, deberas usar el action y los post como estabas haciendolo.

Eso ya te lo dejo a tí.